# What are all of the ways to increase HP regen?

Tags: runescape

Besides using the Prayer ability that regenerates your HP 2x faster, what are all of the ways to increase your health regeneration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Constitution Wiki](https://runescape.wiki/w/Constitution#Recovering_life_points) page includes the ways to increase health regeneration. I don't believe there are any other ways than what they have listed (I don't know of any at least).

First, the default regeneration rate is 0.1% of the players max Life Points level (rounded down) every six seconds. So, at 9900 Life Points, you will gain 9 points every 6 seconds.

Here are the boosts the Wiki lists:

- [Resting](https://runescape.wiki/w/Rest) - Regenerates at a rate of 1% of the players total health per six seconds (stacks with the default rate as well ie at 99 Constitution, you will get 99 + 9 every 6 seconds).
- [Listening to a musician](https://runescape.wiki/w/Rest#Musician) - Regenerates at a rate of 1% of the players total health per three seconds.
- [Rapid Heal Prayer](https://runescape.wiki/w/Rapid_heal_prayer) - Still the default rate, but at every three seconds.
- [Rapid Renewal Prayer](https://runescape.wiki/w/Rapid_renewal) - Still the default rate, but at every 1.2 seconds.
- A [Regen Bracelet](https://runescape.wiki/w/Regen_bracelet) - Raises the default rate to 0.3% per six seconds.
- The [Regeneration Aura](https://runescape.wiki/w/Regeneration_aura) - Doubles the rate at which health regenerates (0.2% at six seconds) .
- The [Fortitude](https://runescape.wiki/w/Fortitude) prayer - Stacks with the default regeneration - essentially doubles the rate (0.2% every six seconds).
- The [Dream](https://runescape.wiki/w/Dream) Lunar Spell - This one is difficult to interpret from the Wiki, and I haven't done the quest needed to unlock the spell.  According to it, it results in 100 life points per minute, making it 1.67 a second, or 10.02 (10) every 6 seconds.
- The [Constitution cape](https://runescape.wiki/w/Constitution_cape) perk - Doubles the rate at which health regenerates. Stacks with fortitude. The perk can also be used with a max cape or a completionist cape.
- Entering a bank - About 500 points per second.